# In python, how can i return all tuples in a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So this is my list:

```
list_tuple = [(x1,x2,x3)(x4,x5,x6)(x7,x8,x9)]
```

and I want to return only all tuples.

How can I return all tuples?

This is what I tried:

```
for i in list_tuple: 
   print(i)
```

This is what it did:

```
x1,x2,x3
```

The result expected is:

```
(x1,x2,x2)
(x4,x5,x6)
(x7,x8,x9)
```

Comment: Your definition of `list_tuple` is invalid - you are missing commas between the tuples. How are you actually declaring `list_tuple`? For me, you get the expected result if you declare it as `list_tuple = [(x1, x2, x3), (x4, x5, x6), (x7, x8, x9)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i,j,k in list_tuple:
  print(i,j,k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    list_tuple = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
    for tp in list_tuple:
        print(tp)
```